# SQL запрос в python скрипте возвращает OperationalError: near ")"

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

У меня есть следующая функция:

```
def initialise_database(db: object):

    if db.__class__ == sql_lite3_db:

        # sqlite3 doesn't handle date type, so date_of_creation and other similar variables must be in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
        # creating table, which represents the forum class
        # structure of table forum: name, date_of_creation, id

        db.excute_query("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS forum (
                name TEXT,
                date_of_creation TEXT,
                id TEXT ,
            )
        """)

        # structure of table user: password, user_id, is_admin, is_banned, logo_path, citate, time_of_join, token

        db.excute_query("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
                password TEXT,
                user_id TEXT UNIQUE,
                is_admin BOOLEAN,
                is_banned BOOLEAN,
                logo_path TEXT,
                citate TEXT,
                time_of_join TEXT,
                token TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
            )
        """)

                

        # creating table threads, which represents the thread class
        # structure of table thread: id_forum, id_thread, name, time_of_creation, author, decrypt (description)

        db.excute_query("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS thread (
                id_forum TEXT REFERENCES forum(id),
                id_thread TEXT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
                time_of_creation TEXT,
                author TEXT REFERENCES user(user_id),
                decrypt TEXT
            )
        """)

        # structure of table topic time_of_creation|theme|author|about|sb_id


        db.excute_query("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS topic(
                time_of_creation TEXT,
                theme TEXT, 
                author TEXT REFERENCES user(user_id),
                about TEXT,
                sb_id TEXT REFERENCES thread(id_thread)


            )
                  
                  
                  
                  """)

                
        # creating table messages, which represents the message class
        # structure of table messages: id_thread, message_id, author, text, time_of_publication

        db.excute_query("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
                id_thread TEXT REFERENCES thread(id_thread),
                message_id TEXT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
                author TEXT REFERENCES user(user_id),
                text_of_publication TEXT,
                time_of_publication TEXT
            )
        """)



        
    elif db.__class__ == postgres_db:

        # sqlite3 didn't handle date type, so date_of_creation and other similar variables must be like YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
        #creating table, which represents the forum class
        #structure of table forum : name;date_of_creasting;id

        #structure of table user password|user_id|is_admin|is_banned|logo_path|citate|time_of_join

        db.excute_query(""" 

                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
                    password TEXT,
                    user_id text UNIQUE,
                    is_admin BOOLEAN,
                    is_banned BOOLEAN,
                    logo_path TEXT,
                    citate TEXT,
                    time_of_join date,
                )
                         
                         
                         """)

        db.excute_query("""

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS forum (
        name TEXT,
        date_of_creation date,
        forum_id TEXT,
    )

                        """)
        
        #creating table threads, which represents the thread class
        #structure of table: id_forum|id_thread|name|time_of_creation|author|decrpt (description)

        db.excute_query("""
                        
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS thread (
        id_forum TEXT REFERENCES forum(id),
        id_thread TEXT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
        time_of_creation date,
        author TEXT REFERENCES user(user),
        decrpt TEXT,
    )

                        
""")


        #creating table messages, which represents the messages class
        #structure of table messages : |id_thd|mess_id|author|text|time_of_publication

        db.excute_query(""" 
                        
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
        id_thd TEXT REFERENCES thread(id_thread),
        mess_id TEXT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
        author TEXT REFERENCES user(user),
        text_of_publication TEXT,
        time_of_publication date,
    )


                        """)


        db.excute_query("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS topic(
                time_of_creation date,
                theme TEXT, 
                author TEXT REFERENCES user(user_id),
                about TEXT,
                sb_id TEXT REFERENCES thread(id_thread)


            )
                  
                  
                  
                  """)


    else:
        raise TypeError('object must be in databases classes, not in other')
```

db - объект класса, у них есть метод excute_query. Я передаю объект класса "sql_lite3_db" и мне возвращается

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

Подскажите, где в моих SQL скриптах ошибка?

Comment: Покажите **полный трейс ошибки**, сейчас непонятно даже, на какую конкретно строку кода ругается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно везде убрать запятые перед скобкой

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS forum (
                name TEXT,
                date_of_creation TEXT,
                id TEXT ,<--------------------------Эти
            )
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогает

Comment: @Евграф Котовский Полностью вывод ошибки, и код, куда указывает ошибка, номер строк там как-нибудь, в вопрос дополнительно покажи.

Comment: у меня заработало, я просто не так запускал сервер, но все равно спасибо за помощь!